# HTTP Caching for authenticated REST apis

Tags: rest, api, http, caching

I'm currently building a REST API. Many of the resources I'm creating will always be identical regardless of who's accessing the resource. The few that aren't will have a `Vary: Authorization` header.

There's two exceptions:

1. You will get a 401 response if you're not authenticated.
2. You might get a 403 response for some resources that you don't have access to.

My question is, in this scenario would it still be possible to setup Caching correctly. In particular, I would like to use a reverse proxy such as nginx, varnish or haproxy to offload the main service.

Are there elegant solutions to this problem?

Comment: Do the URIs of the resources that vary match those that don't? e.g. do you have a /user/joe which either returns public information, information only visible to some users, and information only visible to Joe?

Comment: @Nicholas maybe I wasn't super clear, but for most resources this is *not* the case, and for those that do they will have `Vary: Authorization`. I'm only interested in the resources that are not like that though. Those always have the same response for 200 OK, or they are 401/403.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Vary: Authorization` is unnecessary; responses to requests with Authorization are automatically private, and won't be cached by shared caches.

You can send `Cache-Control: public` to override this; responses with that can be cached using the normal rules.

However, if you want those responses to remain authenticated, you need to impose authentication. You can do that by also sending `Cache-Control: no-cache`, which will force the cache to check with the origin before serving a stored response.

If you **just** want to have your reverse proxy (e.g., Varnish, nginx) do the caching, it's likely that it has a way of being configured to impose authentication on the "edge", serving the responses from cache when the request has the proper authentication. Check its documentation for details.

Comment: Thanks! Always great to get an answer straight from the source :)

Comment: How does Cache-Control: no-cache help with imposing Authentication? Is it because It would try to re-validate the cached item with the server, which means it has to send a request, and that request needs to be authenticated to even get a 304 from the server ?